# Gradient shape background on bottom layout

Tags: android, background, gradient, shapes

here is some UI behavior I don't understand...

What I want:

[image: This is what I would like to achieve]

What I got:

[image: This is real result]

My code:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/black_to_white" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_to_red" />
</LinearLayout>
```

backgrounds code: (same code for both, except the colors)

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#000000"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

How can I make my 2nd gradient start blue at the middle of the screen?

(I noticed the gradient works fine on android 3.0 view mode, but not on other versions)

Comment: It really would be better if you provided xml for drawable not working. Also, did you try using same black_to_white background for both framelayouts already?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following code and it is working fine as you need.

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#151B8D"
        android:endColor="#ff0000"
        android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you lack the alpha in your color code:

```
#[alpha][red][green][blue]
```